# PFQueryTableViewController...Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to display a list of contacts from Parse.com using the `PFQueryTableViewController`, however I can display the data from Parse.com. Now I add a `Bool` in other column from Parse.com, so I want to to display the contact if the `Bool` in the other column is true, any idea?

I can not post Image I do not have enough reputation.

Best regards

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) // Configure the PFQueryTableView 
  self.parseClassName = PF_USER_CLASS_NAME self.textKey = "fullname"
  self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true 
  self.paginationEnabled = false 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your existing code, and your attempt at incorporating this new variable into your query?

Comment: @ÁngelJavierCarrilloBermejo When you post code please add it to the question and format it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a query constraint to filter the `Bool` is `false` like so:

`query.whereKey("boolColumn", equalTo:true)`

Then, it will return objects that `boolColumn` is `true`.